# Wrap groupings of tags with Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to use BeautifulSoup to wrap an element tag around a grouping of tags?

I have a document like this:

```
<h1>Heading for Sec 1</h1>
    <p>some text sec 1</p>
    <p>some text sec 1</p>
    <p>some text sec 1</p>

<h1>Heading for Sec 2</h1>
    <p>some text sec 2</p>
    <p>some text sec 2</p>
    <p>some text sec 2</p>

<h1>Heading for Sec 3</h1>
    <p>some text sec 3</p>
    <p>some text sec 3</p>
```

I need to wrap each grouping with an  tag. Each grouping begins with an  tag. So the output would be:

```
<div>
<h1>Heading for Sec 1</h1>
    <p>some text sec 1</p>
    <p>some text sec 1</p>
    <p>some text sec 1</p>
</div>

<div>
<h1>Heading for Sec 2</h1>
    <p>some text sec 2</p>
    <p>some text sec 2</p>
    <p>some text sec 2</p>
</div>

<div>
<h1>Heading for Sec 3</h1>
    <p>some text sec 3</p>
    <p>some text sec 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Idk about beautifulsoup, but if you are using VS code, the find-and-replace function supports regex, so you could just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<h1>Heading for Sec 1</h1>
    <p>some text sec 1</p>
    <p>some text sec 1</p>
    <p>some text sec 1</p>

<h1>Heading for Sec 2</h1>
    <p>some text sec 2</p>
    <p>some text sec 2</p>
    <p>some text sec 2</p>

<h1>Heading for Sec 3</h1>
    <p>some text sec 3</p>
    <p>some text sec 3</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

last_div = None
for tag in soup.select("h1, p"):   # or soup.find_all(["h1", "p"], recursive=False) if there are inner tags
    if tag.name == "h1":
        last_div = tag.wrap(soup.new_tag("div"))
        last_div.insert(0, "\n")
        last_div.append("\n")
        continue

    last_div.append(tag)
    last_div.append("\n")

# remove unnecessary spaces:
soup.smooth()
for t in soup.find_all(text=True, recursive=False):
    t.replace_with("\n")

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<div>
<h1>Heading for Sec 1</h1>
<p>some text sec 1</p>
<p>some text sec 1</p>
<p>some text sec 1</p>
</div>
<div>
<h1>Heading for Sec 2</h1>
<p>some text sec 2</p>
<p>some text sec 2</p>
<p>some text sec 2</p>
</div>
<div>
<h1>Heading for Sec 3</h1>
<p>some text sec 3</p>
<p>some text sec 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Beutiful! That works perfectly. Thank you so much.

I should have also asked how I would then wrap a <span> tag around heach <p> grouping.

like this:

'```
<div>
<h1>Heading for Sec 1</h1>
<span>
 <p>some text sec 1</p>
 <p>some text sec 1</p>
 <p>some text sec 1</p>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @elbourne You can open a new question here on StackOverflow - but as a hint: append to `last_div` a new `<span>` tag and then add all `<p>` to this tag.